# Probability of growth hormone usage

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a probability theory task, but I cannot get an idea of how one can solve it. Even, I don't understand question well. Any help is appreciated:

Usage of growth hormones $s_1, s_2, s_3$ leads to certain biological effect with probabilities $p_1, p_2, p_3$. There were $n$ experiments using only one of the hormones. The probabilities that in the experiments was used $s_1, s_2, s_3$ are $W_1, W_2, W_3$ respectively. The positive effect was in $m$ experiments. What is the probability that $s_1$ was used in the experiments?

Comment: It sounds like the question is a somewhat confused Bayesian inference, in which $W_i$ are the prior probabilities and the expected distributions of the number of experiments that show the effect are the binomial distributions $B(n, p_i)$.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

\begin{align}
P(\textrm{Positive effect}|s_i)&=p_i,\quad i\in\{1,2,3\}\\
P(s_i)&=W_i,\quad i\in\{1,2,3\}
\end{align}

Assuming independent trials:
\begin{align}
P(\textrm{Positive effect in $m$ out of $n$ experiments}|s_i)&=C_m^np_i^m(1-p_i)^{n-m},\quad i\in\{1,2,3\}
\end{align}

Using Bayes theorem:
\begin{align}
P(s_1|\textrm{Positive effect in $m$ out of $n$ experiments})=\frac{P(\textrm{Positive effect in $m$ out of $n$ experiments}|s_1)P(s_1)}{\sum_{i=1}^3 P(\textrm{Positive effect in $m$ out of $n$ experiments}|s_i)P(s_i)}
\end{align}